# Android studio Giraffe debugger not working, no variables shown in the lower left of my screen

Tags: android-studio, debugging, android-studio-girafee

I am using android studio Giraffe
when i add breaks to the code in my app, and i run in debug mode, it doesn't show any of the variables in the lower left window such as i see in so many examples.

i have looked all over the internet and in youtube videos.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qzdn.jpg)

Any ideas why I can't see the variables when I'm in the debugging mode ??

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided screenshot, firstly, select "Threads and Variables" tab in the debug panel at the bottom of your screen ("Console" is selected In the screenshot). Secondly, put your breakpoints at the beginning of a line, for instance, you should put your breakpoint at the line containing `String url = "some url"` or its next line which is `StartActivity`.

Comment: ok, thank you very much Mostafa.,   kevin rea

Comment: Hi Mostafa, on another note, if I may ask of you, your expertise, i have posed another question on the same android studio java program i have been writing, if you wouldn't mind having a look ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956905/android-studio-java-password-entry-calculation-is-not-being-picked-up

thanks,
kevin rea
lancaster, california usa